# Nginx rewrite url issue

Tags: nginx, webserver

I've problem rewriting the url from /index.php?q=account&page=delete&pid=123 to /account/delete/123

Here's my nginx configuration

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/account/(undelete|delete|hide|unhide)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?q=account&page=$1&pid=$2 last;
}
```

my nginx fails to start with this configuration and it does not log any errors however I've tried nginx -t command and it says test is successful

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good use of nginx rewrite. It seems more like a try_files case. Something like

`location ~ ^/account/(undelete|delete|hide|unhide)/([0-9]+)/?$ { 
          try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php?q=account&page=$1&pid=$2 ;
        }`

It might require some extra fine tuning, tho.

Comment: I've tried it with many possible ways but still the same problem.
here's the final try http://3.ii.gl/ryZkaizd.png

Comment: Ok, however, I believe we're talking about two different issues here. If nginx fails to start, and you're certain it's not already running, and it gives no error or syntax complain with the t parameter,  the only things I can think of are permission problems on the error log and or the process file.

Comment: I've verified that it's not permission issue also error_log and access_log are working perfectly( not logging this issue only ), btw nginx version 1.6.3

Comment: What happens if you comment out your rewrites? I cannot imagine that being the cause, but it's better to discard them from the equation. Also, did it ever run, like... when you had just installed? Did you compile it yourself or did you add nginx repos to apt?

Comment: Installed via apt. when i comment out this line nginx still fails to start however i can comment out any other rewrite with no problems.

Comment: What do you mean " i can comment out any other rewrite with no problems". So, there is actually a conf in which you got nginx running?

Comment: Yes, as long as this line "rewrite ^/account/(undelete|delete|hide|unhide)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?q=account&page=$1&pid=$2 last;" not in the conf, it works without any problems.

Comment: I tried adding your line in nginx 1.4.6, then nginx 1.6.0 and now nginx 1.7.1. The only problem I had was that I had to kill running workers before being able to restart the service. But I get no error from your line.

Comment: I've upgraded to nginx 1.7.1 and it works perfectly now, thanks ;)